Select2 is shown twice when opening modal the first time

I have the modal where this modal show the content dynamically by using js. the modal html is like this:
<button type="button" class="openModalBtn btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-sm mb-1"
                                data-template="templateModalEducation" data-title="Education">
                                <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add
                            </button>
<div id="modal" draggable="true" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg hide" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <b class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Modal Title</b>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body pt-0">
                @* Modal content will be injected here *@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

The modal then appends content inside the "modalBody" using the template I provided. One example of a template for the content body is:
<div id="templateModalEducation">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="Requiredinput">Year</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control edu-year">
                <span id="edu-year-validation" class="text-validation"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="Requiredinput">Level</label>
                <select class="form-control select2normalWithouClear edu-level"
                    data-placeholder="Select Education Level">
                    <option></option>
                    @if (Model.EduLevelDropdownList != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var level in Model.EduLevelDropdownList)
                        {
                            <option>@level.CodeName</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
                <span id="edu-level-validation" class="text-validation"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="Requiredinput">Institution Name</label>
                <select class="form-control select2normalWithouClear edu-instituteName"
                    data-placeholder="Select Institution Name">
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="0">Other</option>
                    @if (Model.EduInstitutionDropdownList != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var institute in Model.EduInstitutionDropdownList)
                        {
                            <option>@institute.CodeName</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
                <span id="edu-instituteName-validation" class="text-validation"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control edu-instituteNameOther">
            </div>
            <span id="edu-instituteNameOther-validation" class="text-validation"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-end m-0 p-0">
        <button id="addEducationRowToMainForm" data-target-table="#tableEducation" type="button"
            class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-sm mb-1">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add
        </button>
        <button id="updateEducationRow" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-sm mb-1"
            style="display: none;">
            <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Update
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

This is my JavaScript code that dynamically changes the content of the modal:
<script>
    // Function to load different template content into the modal
    function loadModalContent(templateId, title) {

        // Clear previous content to prevent duplication
        $('#modalBody').empty(); 
        $('#modalBody .select2normalWithouClear').select2('destroy');

        // Load new content and set the title
        var templateContent = $('#' + templateId).html();  // Get the content of the template
        $('#modalBody').html(templateContent);             // Inject content into the modal body
        $('#modalTitle').text(title);                      // Set the modal title

        $('#modalBody .select2normalWithouClear').select2({
            placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder')
        });

        $('.edu-instituteNameOther').hide();

        $('#modal').modal('show');                         // Show the modal
    }

    // Event listener for buttons that trigger the modal with different templates
    $(document).on('click', '.openModalBtn', function () {
        var templateId = $(this).data('template');         // Get the template to load
        var modalTitle = $(this).data('title');            // Get the title for the modal

        loadModalContent(templateId, modalTitle);          // Call the function to load the content

        TMCEWoFileUpl("250", "");
    });
</script>

The problem is that when I open the modal after the page loads, it displays two dropdowns: one functions correctly, while the other seems to be a duplicate and does not work. However, when I open the modal a second time, the dropdown displays correctly and is not duplicated. Can someone help me fix this?
I’ve tried initializing it outside the modal, but it still doesn't work.
This is a live demo:


// Function to load different template content into the modal
function loadModalContent(templateId, title) {

  // Clear previous content to prevent duplication
  $('#modalBody').empty();
  $('#modalBody .select2normalWithouClear').select2('destroy');

  // Load new content and set the title
  var templateContent = $('#' + templateId).html(); // Get the content of the template
  $('#modalBody').html(templateContent); // Inject content into the modal body
  $('#modalTitle').text(title); // Set the modal title

  $('#modalBody .select2normalWithouClear').select2({
    placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder')
  });

  $('.edu-instituteNameOther').hide();

  $('#modal').modal('show'); // Show the modal
}

// Event listener for buttons that trigger the modal with different templates
$(document).on('click', '.openModalBtn', function() {
  var templateId = $(this).data('template'); // Get the template to load
  var modalTitle = $(this).data('title'); // Get the title for the modal

  loadModalContent(templateId, modalTitle); // Call the function to load the content

  //TMCEWoFileUpl("250", "");
});
<link href="~/lib/jquery-ui-1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery-ui-1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-jnSuA4Ss2PkkikSOLtYs8BlYIeeIK1h99ty4YfvRPAlzr377vr3CXDb7sb7eEEBYjDtcYj+AjBH3FLv5uSJuXg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-ykZ1QQr0Jy/4ZkvKuqWn4iF3lqPZyij9iRv6sGqLRdTPkY69YX6+7wvVGmsdBbiIfN/8OdsI7HABjvEok6ZopQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button type="button" class="openModalBtn btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-sm mb-1"
                            data-template="templateModalEducation" data-title="Education">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add
                        </button>

<div id="modal" draggable="true" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg hide" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <b class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Modal Title</b>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body pt-0">
        @* Modal content will be injected here *@
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="templateModalEducation">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="Requiredinput">Year</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control edu-year">
        <span id="edu-year-validation" class="text-validation"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="Requiredinput">Level</label>
        <select class="form-control select2normalWithouClear edu-level" data-placeholder="Select Education Level">
          <option></option>
          <option value="1">Option1</option>
          <option value="2">Option2</option>
          <option value="3">Option3</option>
          <!--
            @if (Model.EduLevelDropdownList != null)
            {
                foreach (var level in Model.EduLevelDropdownList)
                {
                    <option>@level.CodeName</option>
                }
            }
          -->
        </select>
        <span id="edu-level-validation" class="text-validation"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="Requiredinput">Institution Name</label>
        <select
          class="form-control select2normalWithouClear edu-instituteName"
          data-placeholder="Select Institution Name"
        >
          <option></option>
          <option value="0">Other</option>
          <option value="1">Option1</option>
          <option value="2">Option2</option>
          <option value="3">Option3</option>
          <!--
            @if (Model.EduInstitutionDropdownList != null) {
              foreach (var institute in Model.EduInstitutionDropdownList) {
                <option>@institute.CodeName</option>
              }
            }
          -->
        </select>
        <span id="edu-instituteName-validation" class="text-validation"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control edu-instituteNameOther">
      </div>
      <span id="edu-instituteNameOther-validation" class="text-validation"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-end m-0 p-0">
    <button
      id="addEducationRowToMainForm"
      data-target-table="#tableEducation"
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-sm mb-1"
    >
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add
    </button>
    
    <button
      id="updateEducationRow"
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-sm mb-1"
      style="display: none;"
    >      
      <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Update
    </button>
  </div>
</div>




I edited the question adding a live snippet (hidden by default to avoid cluttering your contents) having all the required assets and stressing out it's using the bootstrap modal. I hope it will help someone finding a solution

please provide a [mre], I can't reprodure the same issue like in your image, it's missing the .data() of some elements

The snippet (added by @DiegoD ?) is missing select2.css, which is why it is showing a normal select and a blank textbox.  This doesn't appear to replicate OPs issue which shows select2's drop down icon/arrow in the screenshot.  As there's no script/link tags in OPs original code, I've assumed this was just an oversight and added it to the snippet.

@fdomn-m isn't the select2.css asset included from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css? I just reformatted the OP's code, commented some parts (the loops in the html template and one ajax call), added the assets (including bootstrap modal that wasn't cited in the question but clearly used). So in general all the assets included come from my side but I don't see how that detail is changing the OP's question. It was intended to highlight the problem in the question not to change it

to keep things as close to the original as possible, the live snippet didn't also take care of actually initializing things.. since $(document).on('click', '.openModalBtn'of course won't have any effect since there's no .openModalBtn. That live snippet is never going to initialize the select2 dropdowns because there's no entry point. So that's the reason why you see them as vanilla. The css is there

@DiegoD there wasn't a select2.min.css in your edit - I added it.   It was just an oversight.   I suspect OPs issue could be due to different versions and/or the modal, neither of which are an issue in the snippet.   Ideally OP needs to provide the CDN links themselves rather than us second-guess.

ah ok good point.. I didn't consider you modified it.. I just took for granted it came from my side. Thanks for the correction

Your loadModalContent function clears the #modalBody before it tries to destroy the Select2 instance on the child element. That should probably be reversed - destroy the Select2 instance before clearing the content.

I’ve found a solution based on a comment by aurelian-scarlat in this GitHub issue

If your box has a class named select2, you'll run into trouble because there are some other elements with the same class.
So this is wrong:$('.select2').select2('destroy');
The correct way is:
$('select.select2').select2('destroy');
Or change the class of the box: $('.select-select2').select2('destroy');
Or even better, use an id: $('#selectbox').select2('destroy');

It took me a while to figure this out, I hope it helps somebody.
I cannot use the class name .select2normalWithouClear because there are some other elements with the same class. So what i did was give the new class name same for all my select and initialized them like this:


<select class="form-control select2normalWithouClear edu-level mySelectDropdown" data-placeholder="Select Education Level"><option>Test 1</option><option>Test 2</option><option>Test 3</option></select>

<select class="form-control select2normalWithouClear edu-instituteName mySelectDropdown" data-placeholder="Select Institution Name"><option>Test 1</option><option>Test 2</option><option>Test 3</option></select>



Initilize it:


$('.mySelectDropdown').select2({ placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder') });



